# How to create several pages using the same template with gatsby-node?

Tags: gatsby

**Individual Project Pages**
I'm creating a unique page for each markdown file using Template A and this is working as expected. They're each children of the following Project Type pages (e.g., www.site/motion-graphics/project-1)

**Project Type Pages**
I'm also trying to create 4 different pages using Template B (project-type.jsx). Each will have a unique path and I will be passing a different "key" for each page. That key will be used to grab specific markdown files with a matching "key". All of these markdown files with the matching key will be displayed. These 4 pages are the Project Type pages (e.g., www.site/motion-graphics).

Essentially what is happening, is the individual project pages are being created correctly, but the 4 project type pages are not being generated at all. I double-checked in GraphQL for all generated pages, as instructed at https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/creating-and-modifying-pages/. **What am I doing wrong in the generation of the 4 Project Type pages?**

Here is my gatsby-node.js file:

```
const path = require('path')

exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, actions }) => {
    
    const { data } = await graphql(`
        query Projects {
            mograph: allMarkdownRemark(
                filter: {frontmatter: {typeKey: {eq: "mograph"}}}
            ) {
                nodes {
                    frontmatter {
                        slug
                    }
                }
            }
            photoedit: allMarkdownRemark(
                filter: {frontmatter: {typeKey: {eq: "photoedit"}}}
            ) {
                nodes {
                    frontmatter {
                        slug
                    }
                }
            }
            photoman: allMarkdownRemark(
                filter: {frontmatter: {typeKey: {eq: "photoman"}}}
            ) {
                nodes {
                    frontmatter {
                        slug
                    }
                }
            }
            webdev: allMarkdownRemark(
                filter: {frontmatter: {typeKey: {eq: "webdev"}}}
            ) {
                nodes {
                    frontmatter {
                        slug
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    `)

    // Individual Project Pages

    data.mograph.nodes.forEach(node => {
        actions.createPage({
            path: '/motion-graphics/' + node.frontmatter.slug,
            component: path.resolve('./src/templates/project-details.jsx'),
            context: { slug: node.frontmatter.slug }
        })
    })

    data.photoedit.nodes.forEach(node => {
        actions.createPage({
            path: '/photo-editing/' + node.frontmatter.slug,
            component: path.resolve('./src/templates/project-details.jsx'),
            context: { slug: node.frontmatter.slug }
        })
    })

    data.photoman.nodes.forEach(node => {
        actions.createPage({
            path: '/photo-manipulation/' + node.frontmatter.slug,
            component: path.resolve('./src/templates/project-details.jsx'),
            context: { slug: node.frontmatter.slug }
        })
    })

    data.webdev.nodes.forEach(node => {
        actions.createPage({
            path: '/web-development/' + node.frontmatter.slug,
            component: path.resolve('./src/templates/project-details.jsx'),
            context: { slug: node.frontmatter.slug }
        })
    })

    //Project Type Pages

    createPage({
        path: '/motion-graphics',
        component: require.resolve('./src/templates/project-type.jsx'),
        context: { typeKey: 'mograph' }
    })
      
    createPage({
        path: '/photo-editing',
        component: require.resolve('./src/templates/project-type.jsx'),
        context: { typeKey: 'photoedit' }
    })

    createPage({
        path: '/photo-manipulation',
        component: require.resolve('./src/templates/project-type.jsx'),
        context: { typeKey: 'photoman' }
    })

    createPage({
        path: '/web-development',
        component: require.resolve('./src/templates/project-type.jsx'),
        context: { typeKey: 'webdev' }
    })
}
```

And here's my template file, project-type.jsx:

```
import * as React from "react"
import { graphql } from "gatsby"
import { Themed } from "theme-ui"
import Layout from "@lekoarts/gatsby-theme-cara/src/components/layout"
import { UpDown, UpDownWide } from "@lekoarts/gatsby-theme-cara/src/styles/animations"
import Svg from "@lekoarts/gatsby-theme-cara/src/components/svg"
import Seo from "@lekoarts/gatsby-theme-cara/src/components/seo"
import Inner from "@lekoarts/gatsby-theme-cara/src/elements/inner"
import "../styles/projects.scss"
import Navbar from "../@lekoarts/gatsby-theme-cara/components/project-nav"
import { GatsbyImage } from "gatsby-plugin-image"
import ProjectCard from "../@lekoarts/gatsby-theme-cara/components/project-card"
import ContentNoParallax from "../elements/content-no-parallax.tsx"

const ProjectType = ({ data }) => {

  const projects = data.projects.nodes
  const typeKey = data.projects.nodes.frontmatter.typeKey

  return (
    <Layout>
      <Seo title={ typeKey } />
      <div>
        <UpDown>
          <Svg icon="triangle" hiddenMobile width={48} stroke color="icon_orange" left="10%" top="20%" />
          <Svg icon="hexa" width={48} stroke color="icon_red" left="60%" top="70%" />
          <Svg icon="box" width={6} color="icon_darker" left="60%" top="15%" />
        </UpDown>
        <UpDownWide>
          <Svg icon="arrowUp" hiddenMobile width={16} color="icon_blue" left="80%" top="10%" />
          <Svg icon="triangle" width={12} stroke color="icon_brightest" left="90%" top="50%" />
          <Svg icon="circle" width={16} color="icon_darker" left="70%" top="90%" />
          <Svg icon="triangle" width={16} stroke color="icon_darkest" left="30%" top="65%" />
          <Svg icon="cross" width={16} stroke color="icon_pink" left="28%" top="15%" />
          <Svg icon="circle" width={6} color="icon_darkest" left="75%" top="10%" />
          <Svg icon="upDown" hiddenMobile width={8} color="icon_darkest" left="45%" top="10%" />
        </UpDownWide>
        <Svg icon="circle" hiddenMobile width={24} color="icon_darker" left="5%" top="70%" />
        <Svg icon="circle" width={6} color="icon_darkest" left="4%" top="20%" />
        <Svg icon="circle" width={12} color="icon_darkest" left="50%" top="60%" />
        <Svg icon="upDown" width={8} color="icon_darkest" left="95%" top="90%" />
        <Svg icon="upDown" hiddenMobile width={24} color="icon_darker" left="40%" top="80%" />
        <Svg icon="triangle" width={8} stroke color="icon_darker" left="25%" top="5%" />
        <Svg icon="circle" width={64} color="icon_green" left="95%" top="5%" />
        <Svg icon="box" hiddenMobile width={64} color="icon_purple" left="5%" top="90%" />
        <Svg icon="box" width={6} color="icon_darkest" left="10%" top="10%" />
        <Svg icon="box" width={12} color="icon_darkest" left="40%" top="30%" />
        <Svg icon="hexa" width={16} stroke color="icon_darker" left="10%" top="50%" />
        <Svg icon="hexa" width={8} stroke color="icon_darker" left="80%" top="70%" />
        <ContentNoParallax>
        <Inner>
          <Themed.h1>Projects</Themed.h1>
          <Themed.h2>
            { typeKey }
          </Themed.h2>
          <Navbar></Navbar>
          <Themed.div className="projects">
            {projects.map(project => (
              <ProjectCard className="project" link={ typeKey } key={ project.id } bg="linear-gradient(to right, #D4145A 0%, #FBB03B 100%)" title={ project.frontmatter.title }>
                <GatsbyImage image={ project.frontmatter.thumb.childImageSharp.gatsbyImageData }></GatsbyImage>                    
                <Themed.p>{ project.frontmatter.description }</Themed.p>                      
              </ProjectCard>
            ))}
          </Themed.div>
        </Inner>
        </ContentNoParallax>
      </div>
    </Layout>
  );
}

export const query = graphql`
query ProjectData($typeKey: String) {
  projects: allMarkdownRemark(
    sort: {fields: frontmatter___date, order: DESC}
    filter: {frontmatter: {typeKey: {eq: $typeKey}}}
  ) {
    nodes {
      id
      frontmatter {
        title
        slug
        description
        typeKey
        thumb {
          childImageSharp {
            gatsbyImageData(
              placeholder: BLURRED
            )
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
`;

export default ProjectType
```

Comment: What do you mean by "but the 4 project type pages are not"? What's the issue?

Comment: I've updated that sentence for clarity's sake. It now reads "...but the 4 project type pages are not being generated at all. I double-checked in GraphQL for all generated pages, as instructed at https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/creating-and-modifying-pages/."

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried filtering by `key` instead of `typeKey` in the `project-type.jsx`?

```
export const query = graphql`
query ProjectData($key: String) {
  projects: allMarkdownRemark(
    sort: {fields: frontmatter___date, order: DESC}
    filter: {frontmatter: {typeKey: {eq: $key}}}
  ) {
    nodes {
      id
      frontmatter {
        title
        slug
        description
        typeKey
        thumb {
          childImageSharp {
            gatsbyImageData(
              placeholder: BLURRED
            )
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
`;
```

I assume the field in the markdown file is named `typeKey` because you are querying it (despite in your question you said `key`), however, the variable you are passing to your template is named `key` because of:

```
context: { key: 'photoman' }
```

I suggest using the same naming convention to avoid this kind of issue, but essentially, you are passing a `key` field that was being received as `typeKey`, which doesn't match, so the query wasn't filtering.

As per the project template, I think you don't need to create pages using `gatsby-node.js` as long as you already know the slug (`/motion-graphics`, `/photo-editing`, `/photo-manipulation` and `/web-development`) so you can just create 4 files inside `/pages` folder named `motion-graphics.js`, `photo-editing.js`, `photo-manipulation.js` and `web-development.js` and place there a filtered (by `key`) [page query](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/querying-data/page-query/).

Comment: When I initially created this post, I was using the fieldname, "key" in my markdown files. I realized later that my component, "ProjectCard" also accepts a "key" argument, so I thought it would be wise to rename "key" to "typeKey" in my markdown files. What would you recommend doing in this scenario? I've updated my post to use "typeKey" in the "gatsby-node.js" file, since that's what I'm currently having problems with. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: It's a matter of naming and taste. I personally prefer `key` as is but it has no affection in the end. Whatever you choose I'd recommend you to keep it consistent (i.e: using same convention across the project). Regarding the issue, can be related to the fact that you are using `actions.createPage` and `createPage`? I'm not sure what are isolated parts of the code or not.

Comment: That's all fair. I wasn't sure if the two different uses of "key" would interfere with each other, so thanks for the clarity. In regards to the issue, is there a way to create a single page using "actions.createPage" or is my current approach closer to the preferred method? I can update my post with additional information if need be.

Comment: I think you don't need to create dynamic pages using `gatsby-node.js` as long as you already know the slug of the page. You can just create a `motion-graphic.js` (and so on for the rest) and create there a page query to fetch all the needed data

Comment: Is this the best approach here? Each page will be identical, with the exception of the markdown file data. I figured it'd be more efficient if I ever need to make updates to said template. Thoughts?

Comment: In that case, the best approach (in my opinion) is to use one single loop to create pages for each "project detail type", passing the `key` field via context. In your template, then, use that `key` to filter the query to get the specific data for each type (you may need to refine the data once queried in your `gatsby-node.js` to get one single array of types. This will result in one single loop (vs 4 now) and keeping the specificity of the data (send the unique value via context). Otherwise, the context is useless and you are creating dynamic pages for static and known pages

Comment: That makes perfect sense, but I'm not sure what that would look like in practice... If you could update your answer with an example, I'd truly appreciate it.